How can I create hourly dates by group and assign missing values of a variable with the means of non missing data of that variable in Oracle SQL?
I am working with a table that registers the hourly measurements taken by some devices our clients' have purchased. A mock sample of it can be created with the following code in python:
contract_code = [1927318] * 24 + [73812631] * 24
client_code = ["090909"] * 24 + ["101010"] * 24
device = ["QWERTY"] * 24 + ["ASDFG"] * 24
one_day_hourly_data = pd.date_range(
    start=datetime.datetime(2024, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0),
    end=datetime.datetime(2024, 5, 6, 23, 59, 59),
    freq="1h",
).to_list()
measurements = np.random.randint(low=0, high=4000, size=24 * 2)


mock_data_dict = {
    "contract_code": contract_code,
    "client_code": client_code,
    "device": device,
    "measurement_date_hour": one_day_hourly_data + one_day_hourly_data,
    "measurements": measurements,
}

mock_data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mock_data_dict)

Or the following in Oracle
CALL drop_table_if_exists('device_measurements');
CREATE TABLE device_measurements (
  contract_code,
  client_code,
  device,
  measurement_date_hour,
  measurement
) AS
SELECT 1927318,
       '090909',
       'QWERTY',
       DATE '2024-05-06' + INTERVAL '1' HOUR * (LEVEL - 1),
       TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 4001))
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 24
UNION ALL
SELECT 73812631,
       '101010',
       'ASDFG',
       DATE '2024-05-06' + INTERVAL '1' HOUR * (LEVEL - 1),
       TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 4001))
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 24;

As you can see from the code or by looking at the data, this mock table has one day worth of measurements of 2 different devices that have been purchased by 2 different clients. What I now need to do is to check if the measurements of each device have, at least, three days of hourly data since its last measurement and, if not, I need to create rows until I have three days of data and assign the measurement value of the missing values with the average by hour of non-missing measurements.
I know how to do this in Python but I am struggling to replicate the result in Oracle SQL. What I have done so far is the following:
The first step is to calculate the mean measurements value per client-contract-device and hour. In python:
mean_values = mock_data.groupby(
    [
        "contract_code",
        "client_code",
        "device",
        mock_data.measurement_date_hour.dt.hour,
    ]
).measurements.mean()
mean_values.index.names = ["contract_code", "client_code", "device", "hour"]
mean_values = mean_values.reset_index()

Or in Oracle:
CREATE TABLE so_question_mean_values AS
    SELECT
        contract_code,
        client_code,
        device,
        TO_CHAR(measurement_date_hour, 'HH24'),
        AVG(measurement) AS mean_measurement
    FROM
        device_measurements
    GROUP BY
        contract_code,
        client_code,
        device,
        TO_CHAR(measurement_date_hour, 'HH24');

After that, we need to calculate the start and end dates of each client-contract-device. The end_date will be the last measurement registered in the table, whilst the start_date will be 2 days before that. In python this is done by:
end_date = mock_data.groupby(
    ["contract_code", "client_code", "device"]
).measurement_date_hour.max()
start_date = end_date.apply(lambda x: x - relativedelta(days=2))
mock_data = mock_data.set_index(
    ["measurement_date_hour", "contract_code", "client_code", "device"]
)

And in Oracle:
CREATE TABLE so_question_start_end_dates AS
    SELECT
        contract_code,
        client_code,
        device,
        MAX(measurement_date_hour) AS end_date,
        MAX(measurement_date_hour) - INTERVAL '2' DAY AS start_date
    FROM
        device_measurements
    GROUP BY
        contract_code,
        client_code,
        device;

The next step is to, considering those start and end dates, check if there is a row corresponding to each hour between them and, if not, create them. In python this is done via:
multiindex = [
    [
        (date, group[0], group[1], group[2])
        for date in pd.date_range(
            start=start_date[group], end=end_date[group], freq="1h"
        )
    ]
    for group, _ in mock_data.groupby(["contract_code", "client_code", "device"])
]

flat_index = [x for xs in multiindex for x in xs]
mock_data = mock_data.reindex(flat_index).reset_index()

And this is where I struggle to replicate the process in Oracle I cannot find a way of doing this via query. Could you help me figure it out?
If it is needed, the next step is to assign the mean values per hour (those calculated in the first step) to the now missing measurement that have been created in the previous step. In Python I have done this with this code:
mock_data["hour"] = mock_data.measurement_date_hour.dt.hour

result = pd.concat(
    [
        mock_data[mock_data.measurements.notnull()],
        mock_data.loc[
            mock_data.measurements.isnull(),
            [
                "measurement_date_hour",
                "contract_code",
                "client_code",
                "device",
                "hour",
            ],
        ].merge(
            mean_values,
            how="left",
            on=["contract_code", "client_code", "device", "hour"],
        ),
    ]
).sort_values("measurement_date_hour", ignore_index=True)

This is quite easy to replicate in Oracle because it is quite a simple LEFT JOIN, however, I need the table created in the step before this, and I am not able to get it.
The result of this python code for one contract is the following.

measurement_date_hour   contract_code   client_code device  measurements    hour
0   2024-05-04 23:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  3092.0  23
2   2024-05-05 00:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  3167.0  0
4   2024-05-05 01:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  2633.0  1
6   2024-05-05 02:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  1710.0  2
8   2024-05-05 03:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  2706.0  3
11  2024-05-05 04:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  1375.0  4
13  2024-05-05 05:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  3677.0  5
14  2024-05-05 06:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  2404.0  6
16  2024-05-05 07:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  1949.0  7
18  2024-05-05 08:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  216.0   8
20  2024-05-05 09:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  3685.0  9
22  2024-05-05 10:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  744.0   10
24  2024-05-05 11:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  1683.0  11
27  2024-05-05 12:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  1595.0  12
29  2024-05-05 13:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  2285.0  13
30  2024-05-05 14:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  3435.0  14
32  2024-05-05 15:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  214.0   15
35  2024-05-05 16:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  1034.0  16
37  2024-05-05 17:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  3039.0  17
39  2024-05-05 18:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  2296.0  18
40  2024-05-05 19:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  2734.0  19
42  2024-05-05 20:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  1612.0  20
44  2024-05-05 21:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  3846.0  21
47  2024-05-05 22:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  2489.0  22
48  2024-05-05 23:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  3092.0  23
50  2024-05-06 00:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  3167.0  0
52  2024-05-06 01:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  2633.0  1
54  2024-05-06 02:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  1710.0  2
56  2024-05-06 03:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  2706.0  3
58  2024-05-06 04:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  1375.0  4
61  2024-05-06 05:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  3677.0  5
63  2024-05-06 06:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  2404.0  6
65  2024-05-06 07:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  1949.0  7
66  2024-05-06 08:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  216.0   8
68  2024-05-06 09:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  3685.0  9
70  2024-05-06 10:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  744.0   10
72  2024-05-06 11:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  1683.0  11
74  2024-05-06 12:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  1595.0  12
77  2024-05-06 13:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  2285.0  13
78  2024-05-06 14:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  3435.0  14
80  2024-05-06 15:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  214.0   15
83  2024-05-06 16:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  1034.0  16
85  2024-05-06 17:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  3039.0  17
87  2024-05-06 18:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  2296.0  18
88  2024-05-06 19:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  2734.0  19
90  2024-05-06 20:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  1612.0  20
92  2024-05-06 21:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  3846.0  21
95  2024-05-06 22:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  2489.0  22
97  2024-05-06 23:00:00 1927318 090909  QWERTY  3092.0  23

Any help is much appreciated! And if you need further details to answer the question I will gladly provide them when asked :)
EDIT
As per MT0's comment, I have reduced the example to just two days instead of a month, provided some Oracle SQL code with the table creation and the steps I have already achieved, and provided with the python result I need to recreate in Oracle

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample Oracle data (probably fiddle); an English (not code) explanation of the problem; and the expected output for your sample data (so maybe not random data). At the moment we need to reverse engineer what your python code is doing before we can work out what the Oracle code should be; help us to help you and explain clearly (not in code) what the problem is and what output to expect. Maybe simplify the problem so that you do not need 300 rows of data.
